# Stored Sitecore search using API returns 400 error

Tags: api

I am trying to use stored Sitecore search using an API call from console application, but it is throwing `400 error`. I have followed the sitecore documentation

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html

under the last section "**Run a stored Sitecore search**" section with the URL format provided. The URL which I provided is the following -

```
https://demosc.dev.local/sitecore/api/ssc/item/1FB673FA-C0E0-4174-BA8F-2C170BB71BCD/search?term=State&database=master
```

It seems the URL structure formed is not correct and I am not sure as I followed the example in the documentation. Kindly help me with the same.

Comment: Which Sitecore version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried running this query via Postman and the syntax seems fine to me. Just follow the below steps to make this work.

- First of all, You will need to use this method to authenticate users. It sets the authentication cookie.

```
    https://<your server>/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login
```

[image]

Make sure you are passing, `Content-Type:application/json` in the headers.

- Now, Use the below query to run a Sitecore search that is stored in a search definition item. This means you will need to first create a `Search definition item` in the Sitecore content tree based on the template  `/sitecore/templates/System/Services/Item Service/Search/Search Definition`. You can provide details for this item like database, field name etc.

[image]

Now, run the query on this item,

```
<your server>/sitecore/api/ssc/item/FDFFA0FA-40D4-47F6-87CD-7BC3B1EA6EC2/search?term=Home&database=master
```

[image]

In the result, you would see all the items having search terms in the defined fields

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. It worked like magic. I am able to check the same in postman. But I have one doubt. So this stored search query is to search items only inside any field. For ex, the content inside a rich text editor/single line text or will it retrieve even content items also? Because if it fetches the content items there is another search type called "Run a Sitecore search" which retrieves content items based on search term. so just wanted to understand in which case scenario both needs to be differentiated?